# Application getting stopped abruptly

Tags: java, exception

Im trying to run a java eclipse based application and it has feature to read an excel file.But the application seems to stop abruptly.

Below is the runtime exception that I received.

```
An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment: 
Internal Error   (434F4E5354414E54304F4F4C2F4F500E4350500032), pid=968, tid=3504
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.6.0-b105 mixed mode)
An error report file with more information is saved as hs_err_pid968.log
If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

I have also checked the  hs_err_pid968.log file and below is the details

```
Stack: [0x00370000,0x003c0000)
[error occurred during error reporting, step 110, id 0xc0000005]
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
com.ins.hii.stores.importModel.ImportModelFrmExcel.readXLSAndFetchDetails(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/HashMap;+32
 com.ins.hii.stores.importModel.ImportModelFrmExcel.processXLSAndimportModels(Ljava/lang/String;)V+2
 com.ins.hii.stores.actions.ImportModelAction.run()V+11
  org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+1
```

Any help in resolving the above issue is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: are you using some native code?

Comment: No.Im not using any native code.

Comment: Im not using any native code.  But i have recently included some files which were tested in some other machine. The code works fine in the other machine. But throws some exception in my machine. I have also checked the error log specified in the above error and have updated the error details

Comment: Hmm, in eclipse check the properties of these files to ensure that the encoding is correct.

Comment: I have checked the encoding in the properties of the file and it seems to be the same like the other files in that workspace. the encoding is set to Cp1252